# Tkinter - How to set a variable based off an entrybox user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am looking to make a theme park ticketing program in tkinter, i have already made it in python 3 but i am trying to implement it into tkinter. However, I am unsure on how to set a variable based off a user input in tkinter. I want the program to ask the the user to input an integer for the amount of tickets they would like to buy, this would lead to a variable which can then calculate a cost depending on how many tickets they want. Mainly i would like an input to be taken when they press a button, this would result in a new frame showing. One last thing would be that I have heard maybe using a spinbox to do this would be more effective but i am not really, however, if any of you know how to implement a spin box into my program it would be really helpful.

```
class PageAdultTickets(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="red")
        self.controller = controller
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text="------------- Welcome to Fantasialand Ticket Station ------------", fg="Blue", font=controller.title_font)
        label1.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        label2 = tk.Label(self, text=f"The price of 1 adult ticket is £{adultTicket:0.2f}", fg="steelblue", bg="yellow", font=controller.title_font)
        label2.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=5)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Main Menu",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("MainMenu"))
        button1.pack(side="right")

        v = tk.IntVar()
        amAdultTickets = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=v)
        amAdultTickets.pack(side="bottom")
        s = v.get()
```

Thanks to everyone who tries to help!

Comment: [Tkinter Spinbox](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/spinbox.htm), [tkinter Entry](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm). Hope they help.

Comment: I've already looked at these, i still have a problem of getting the input and making it a variable.

Comment: You have asked same question before and got comments that it is wrong to get the value of the entry just after it is created.  You need to, for example,  create another button that triggers a function to get the value and perform required calculation.

Comment: Yes, but exactly like I said, What is the command to get the entry, telling me my problem which i am fully aware of is not helping at all, I asked it before because i got no genuine response and you posting your very unhelpful question is not going to make me want to post again. So kindly either help me or ignore me. Thanks @acw1668

Comment: You already know how to get the value of the entry: `v.get()`.